# Where clause specific middle left value oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, character, where-clause

i have this query :

```
select s.ST_SAMPLE_ID, s.st_cn_no as CNNumber,
s.st_smptyp as SampleType,
s.st_wasgrp as WasteCode,
s.st_wascod as WasteCategory,
s.st_received_dt as ReceivedDate,
s.st_wastyp_name as WasteType,
s.st_status as SampleStatus,
s.st_dispose_ind as DisposalStatus,
s.st_container as SampleContainer,
s.st_smppnt as SamplePoint,
s.st_nature as SampleNature,
c.scm_name as Color,cm_client_name 
from sample_txn s,sample_color_mstr c,client_mstr cm  
where s.st_color=scm_auto_no (+) and st_client_id=cm_client_id 
and st_year='13' and s.st_lab_id='R'
```

and the result is :

[image: result of the query]

How to filter result by month. I mean filtering from column `RECEIVEDDATE` 3 characters from left e.g JAN, FEB,

i try adding this to where clause

```
LPAD(s.st_received_dt,3,'JAN')
```

but not working and error as :

> SQL Error: ORA-00920: invalid relational operator
>   00920. 00000 -  "invalid relational operator"
>   *Cause:
>   *Action:

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can filter the month by using TO_CHAR function as shown below:

```
select s.ST_SAMPLE_ID, s.st_cn_no as CNNumber,
s.st_smptyp as SampleType,
s.st_wasgrp as WasteCode,
s.st_wascod as WasteCategory,
s.st_received_dt as ReceivedDate,
s.st_wastyp_name as WasteType,
s.st_status as SampleStatus,
s.st_dispose_ind as DisposalStatus,
s.st_container as SampleContainer,
s.st_smppnt as SamplePoint,
s.st_nature as SampleNature,
c.scm_name as Color,cm_client_name 
from sample_txn s,sample_color_mstr c,client_mstr cm  
where s.st_color=scm_auto_no (+) and st_client_id=cm_client_id 
and st_year='13' and s.st_lab_id='R'
and to_char(s.st_received_dt,'MON') = 'JAN';
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand why you would be using `lpad()`.  Try this:

```
to_char(s.st_received_dt, 'MON') = 'JAN'
```

Or:

```
extract(month from s.st_received_dt) = 1
```

Comment: thank you. i will try. sorry i'm newbie and still confused read material form documentation.

Comment: succesfull, i forgot that st_received_dt is format date